# C/C++ CreateFileA fails

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am trying to make an image viewer, and everything works when I hard code the path of the file, but when I try to get the path so I can open files with it, it doesn't work, nothing happens.

When debugging, I found out that `CreateFileA` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

This leads me to believe that the error should be in these 2 lines of code.

```cpp
LPSTR FileA = GetCommandLine();
HANDLE FileHandle = CreateFileA(FileA, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: Check the error code returned by [`GetLastError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror). Also show more code, the problem might be in the part of your code you didn't show.

Answer (score 5):

When `CreateFileA()` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` on failure, use `GetLastError()` to find out WHY it failed. But in this case, `GetCommandLine()` is likely not returning the path you are expecting.

Assuming that is actually calling the Win32 [`GetCommandLineA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinea) function, and not some other function in your program, then that function returns the command line that was used to launch the calling process, ie `"C:\<path>\myapp.exe <parameters>"`.  If there are no `<parameters>` present, then you would be trying to open your own program's EXE, not an image file. And if there are `<parameters>` present, then you would be passing an invalid file path to `CreateFileA()`.

You need to *parse* the command line to extract just the file path you actually want, THEN you can try to open the file at that path.  Have a look at [Parsing C Command-Line Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/parsing-c-command-line-arguments?view=msvc-160) and [Parsing C++ Command-Line Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/17w5ykft(v=vs.85)) .  Consider using [`CommandLineToArgvW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) to make that easier.

Comment: `you would be trying to open your own program's EXE, which is locked by the OS while running`  It seems likely that `GENERIC_READ` / `FILE_SHARE_READ` would succeed.  The OS lock is not exclusive.